# Python Selenium Webdriver Issue - Unable to Find Frame

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on automating a process on a website which contains this HTML source code:

```
<frameset framespacing="0" border="false" frameborder="0" rows="95,*,23" id="TopFr" onload="javascript:ChkFr()">
```

Using the below code to switch to the frame throws up the no such frame exception:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("TopFr")
```

I've also tried using waits, but that doesn't fix the issue. Could it have to do with the "onload" attribute in the source code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, switch_to_frame requires the frame name, not id

You could try driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("TopFr")) instead.

Comment: it actually takes an index, name, or a webelement.